# Validation on IEnumerable not applied - ASP.Net Core Web APIs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-validators

****I have an endpoint that accepts more than one media uploading while sending a List of DTOs no validation applies, validation only work on a single DTO.****

Here is the DTO that endpoint accept as a payload:

```
public class MediaDto
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    [MaxFileSize(20 * 1024 * 1024)]
    [AllowedExtensions(new[] { ".jpg", ".png", ".jpeg", ".tiff", ".raw", ".webm", ".ogg", ".m4v", ".mp4" })]
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    [Required] public int Width { get; set; }
    [Required] public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

The Controller Action

```
public IActionResult AddMedia([FromForm][Required] IEnumerable<MediaDto> media)
{
   return Ok(_momentService.AddMedia(media));
}
```

**Validation Not Applied to the above case**

**If I change the controller action to accept only **one object** the validation will applied**

```
public IActionResult AddMedia([FromForm] MediaDto media)
{
  return Ok(_momentService.AddMedia(media));
}
```

> Custom Validation Attribute

```
public class AllowedExtensionsAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string[] _extensions;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public AllowedExtensionsAttribute(string[] extensions)
    {
        _extensions = extensions;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override ValidationResult? IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value is not IFormFile file) return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage());
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        return !_extensions.Contains(extension.ToLower()) ? new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage()) : ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    private static string GetErrorMessage()
    {
        return $"This photo extension is not allowed!";
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you had the chance debugging to check if the error is coming from `AllowedExtensions` or controller it self?

Comment: The error is coming from custom validation. I will include it

Comment: Could you please double check if it is throwing error in specific file extensionn or for all types of. You can test by considering only one file types, for instance, .jpg or .png. Thus, we can narrow down it.